# BULK Collect and FORALL inserting data twice

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Need help in below!

I have code which have 2 cursors, from first cursor i am getting distinct values and one by one passing them into 2nd cursor(parameterized) from 2nd cursor i am getting result set which i am inserting into a table using BULK COLLECT and FORALL.

i have a scenerio where for value fetched from 1st cursor if data in not found in 2nd cursor then same values from collection are inserted twice into table.

for example:

for emp : 1 i have two dept 2 and 3 which are getting inserted into table- perfect
For emp 2 : there is no dept - 2 and 3 are inserted again - wrong.

please help me in this, i do not want to insert old records from collection if record is not found in 2nd cursor.

**I have found one problem here , when i remove LOOP and LIMIT from BULK collect stmt it works fine however when i add LOOP and LIMIT it inserts data twice.**

Should i use .Delete() method ? where ?

below is sample code

```
  DECLARE

  CURSOR emp_cur IS  
  SELECT DISTINCT emp_id from employee;

  CURSOR get_dept_cur(emp IN VARCHAR2) IS
  SELECT DISTINCT dept from department where dpt_emp_id=emp;

  TYPE nt_emp_metadata IS TABLE OF get_dept_cur%ROWTYPE;
  l_data_array nt_emp_metadata ;

BEGIN
   OPEN emp_cur ;

   LOOP FETCH emp_cur INTO l_emp;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cur %NOTFOUND;     

       OPEN get_dept_cur(l_emp);
        LOOP FETCH get_dept_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_data_array LIMIT 100;
          FORALL i IN 1..l_data_array.COUNT
          INSERT INTO ABC VALUES l_data_array(i);
     EXIT WHEN get_dept_cur%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
        CLOSE get_dept_cur;

   END LOOP;
   CLOSE emp_cur ;
 END;
```

Comment: Did you try some debugging using dbms_output to investigate the problem?

Comment: Where does `l_metadata_array` come from? Also at this point a full example with `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT` and the full `DECLARE..END` block with variable declaration would be helpful to reproduce.

Comment: Hi Vincent it was atypo ...its l_data_array not l_metadata_array which is of type nested table.i have modified code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem? You are getting duplicated records in ABC? That is because you can have the same `dept`value for different employees. If you finally want to insert in ABC all the `dept` for the `emps` it would be easier to do this:

```
INSERT INTO ABC
SELECT d.dept
FROM employee e
JOIN department d
ON e.dept=d.dept
GROUP BY d.dept;
```

Remember: Cursors are the root of all evil :)